# ECS service task is running on 6060 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created ECS cluster and service via Terraform, and I have capacity provider running and managing Autoscaling group for ECS. My application is configured to run on 6060 port, and Host port is set to 0 so I can have dynamic port mapping when running multiple tasks. The problem I've is when I start let say 10 tasks across 3 instances it runs 7 tasks marked as healthy in target group, however 3 tasks are running on port 6060 across 3 EC2 instances, while other 7 tasks have random ports assigned. Those 3 tasks on 6060 port are marked as unhealthy, and constantly failing to start.

I'm not sure why those 3 tasks, each task per instance, are started on port 6060 when I've configured dynamic hosts.
Any ideas ?

Many thanks

Comment: Update: if a new EC2 instance in the autoscaling group is added, the first task under the Target group has 6060 port which is failing. Here's the example: 
https://pasteboard.co/gb2ouxL5JvxI.png